# Logging server crashes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I want to log server crashes, but the exit hook does not work, the process exits but there is no log

```
process.on('exit', async () => {await sendDataToLogServer() });
```

I have also tried beforeExit hook but it does not work like exit hook

```
process.on('beforeExit', async () => {await sendDataToLogServer() });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit` hook is is called when there is no event in event loop anymore or manually we call `process.exit()`
exit hook only supports synchronous task inside it because there is no access to event loop anymore inside it

Even though, `beforeExit` supports async tasks, based on [node document](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit)

> The 'beforeExit' event is not emitted for conditions causing explicit
> termination, such as calling process.exit() or uncaught exceptions

So you have no access to event loop anymore, what you’re gonna do? IF it’s just a log , then the simplest solution might be calling another child process which has access to an event loop

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

process.on('exit', () => {
  childProcess.exec('node ./what-to-do-asynchronously.js');
});
```

Comment: Actually I read some complicated solutions, but this seems really clean..,

Comment: yes, you might have to deal with signals if this does not satisfy your requirement

Answer (score 0):

`exit` and `beforeExit` events are not dispatched when the process crashes. They're triggered when event loop has nothing left to do or `process.exit()` has been called.

In order to catch exceptions use `process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => ...)` or implement concrete error handling in your app.